# Efficient way to compare in-memory list with database list

Tags: entity-framework, linq, optimization, architecture, comparison

Using .NET 6 and Entity Framework, I am trying to an efficient way to find and flag differences between records in the database, based on a composite key. Consider this class with a composite primary key consisting of ID and Year.

```
class Building
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int Year { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public double Size { get; set; }
    public decimal LastSalePrice { get; set; }
}
```

I retrieve in-memory all buildings with Year == 2022.Now I need to compare and flag differences between all the buildings in the list with buildings that have a 2021 year.

The way I see it there are two ways:

1. Need another class to hold flags (this might not be the best way since both the building list along with changes flags needs to be sent to front end, which would require an extra class to put together all the information)
2. Modify the building class by adding 'NameChanged', 'SizeChanged', 'LastSalePriceChanged' bools to flag differences

My goal is to avoid retrieving the list of buildings with a Year of 2021 and then performing item-by-item comparisons in-memory. Instead, I'm looking for a solution that operates at the database level to cleanly flag the differences. For instance, if a building exists in 2022 but not in 2021, all flags should be set to 'true'.

I'm interested in the most efficient approach in terms of performance and resource usage and avoid unnecessary data retrieval.

Thank you!

PS: I've tried retrieving the list of buildings with year '2021' and comparing each building ID but it is very verbose and a 'business logic oriented' solution. It's not the 'clean, data-layer oriented' solution I want.

Comment: *"I'm looking for a solution that operates at the database level to cleanly flag the differences"* If you work with a SQL database and the list is big, AFAIK, the SQL engine cannot do that so any tool/API able to do that will do it inefficiently (certainly by doing 1 request per item which is insane). Retrieving the whole list, or at least chunk of it is certainly much faster (though slow since SQL database are simply not designed for such an operation). If you convert your list to a table, then maybe the SQL engine can compare this efficiently (not sure this is faster than in-memory though).

Comment: Usually, data-oriented isn't "clean" at all and business logic should be cleaner, if "clean" means smaller amount of code. Fetch all data in a class that has all fields twice or contains two nested classes with all 2021 and 2022 data per ID and *let the class contain the logic to show the needed flags as get-only properties*. That's *object-oriented*: data units (objects) that encapsulate the logic working on the data.

Answer (score 0):

If the ID for each year is the same, and the composite unique key is the combination of ID and year, then you could use a self-join:

```
var differingBuildings = await context.Buildings
    .Join(context.Buildings.DefaultIfEmpty(), b1 => b1.Id, b2 => b2.Id,
         (b1, b2) => new { BuildingYear1 = b1, BuildingYear2 = b2 })
    .Where(x => x.BuildingYear1.Year = year1 
        && x.BuildingYear2.Year = year2
        && (x.BuildingYear1.Name != x.BuildingYear2.Name
            || x.BuildingYear1.Size != x.BuildingYear2.Size
            || x.BuildingYear1.LastSalePrice != x.BuildingYear2.LastSalePrice))
    .Select(x => new 
    {
        x.BuildingYear2.Id,
        x.BuildingYear2.Year,
        NameChanged = x.BuildingYear1 == null || x.BuildingYear1.Name != x.BuildingYear2.Name,
        SizeChanged = x.BuildingYear1 == null || x.BuildingYear1.Size != x.BuildingYear2.Size,
        LastSalePriceChanged = x.BuildingYear1 == null || x.BuildingYear1.LastSalePrice != x.BuildingYear2.LastSalePrice
    }).ToListAsync();
```

This would return any buildings for two years where the name, size, or sale price differed, with the latest (assuming year2 > year 1) year and flags for which values changed. This likely isn't going to be a particularly performant query, so depending on the amount of data, it may be more efficient to simply load all buildings (or sets of buildings based on ID) for the two years into memory and do the comparison there.

If Year2 represents data that you have updated in memory anyways, then I would just load Year 1 into memory and compare. There would be no point trying to feed data back to SQL for all buildings to effect some form of join like the above. Fetch the previous year's data and compare in memory. If you have an updated sub-set of IDs that were updated, then you could just fetch the equivalent buildings by ID using that set.

Comment: Don't you need a right join for the case where `year2` matches but `year1` does not? (I would suggest `b1 => new { b1.Id, b1.Year }, b2 => new { b2.Id, Year = b2.Year-1 }` with a right join.)

Comment: Year 1 and 2 are just the two years being compared which would typically be adjacent but wouldn't need to be. I just expressed them as variables rather than 2021 & 2022. Records would need to exist for both years for results to come back, otherwise there is nothing to compare.

Comment: From the original question: "For instance, if a building exists in 2022 but not in 2021, all flags should be set to 'true'."

Comment: Ah, yes good point.  I have updated the answer to apply the DefaultIfEmpty and incorporate if the earlier year was found or not in the flag set.  The Query is written from memory so it may need to be tweaked, I don't commonly write outer joins explicitly.

Comment: I don't think that quite fixes the issue since the `Where` would still kick out if no e.g. `year1` matching building exists, so you need something like `|| x == null`?